# ¿Cuál es el protocolo a seguir con los 'trolls'?

Tags: discusión

Noto con preocupación que este [tipo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/29474/417) de respuestas se están volviendo habituales en el sitio. En una semana ya he reportado 4 respuestas de ese estilo y me inquieta que siga en ascenso. Evidentemente se trata de usuarios que crean perfiles con el único objetivo de responder con groserías e insultos hacia quien pregunta, tal vez con el objeto de intimidar a quien pregunta (quizá cuestiones personales entre conocidos) o sólo personas sin oficio.

Aparte de reportar la respuesta como ofensiva ¿existe algo más que se pueda hacer con estos usuarios?

Comment: Bandera y no entrar en su juego. Poner un comentario es alimentar la conducta troll XD.

Comment: @dwarandae, Por experiencia es mejor *ignorarlos*, al final simplemente se alejan jeje  =).

Comment: No te tomes en serio sus insultos cuando sean detrás de una computadora. La verdad es que hay cada vez más trolls...
Y si no estás satisfecho le das abajo a la izquierda donde dice "reportar".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ya se ha procesado el reporte.

Cuando os encontréis estos casos lo mejor es:

- Reportar como ofensivo.
- Votar para eliminar (si se tiene la reputación suficiente).
- Reportar con un custom flag a un moderador para los casos más graves (dónde el caso que has compartido entra en esta categoría).

Aunque las cuentas que se creen sólo se utilicen para hacer una única respuesta en la mayoría de los casos son usuarios que no tienen ninguna otra cuenta en el sitio y son casos aislados. Cuando se encuentran estos casos siempre se mira a fondo la situación, os lo puedo asegurar.

Comment: Hola Miquel, dijiste `en la mayoría de los casos son usuarios que no tienen ninguna otra cuenta en el sitio` y tengo una duda, ¿como sabes eso?

Comment: Para casos puntuales hay herramientas que, bajo justificación, permiten obtener este tipo de información concreta para saber si estos comentarios abusivos son realizados des de cuentas `dummy`

Comment: Ohh.. excelente! Gracias

Comment: Agrego: **dar un voto negativo**, lo cual permite que la propia comunidad también pueda encargarse: puede entrar en baja calidad para revisión y puede eliminarse, y también permite que los usuarios con 4k puedan votar para eliminarla (10k en sitios que no están en beta).

Comment: @Mariano depende. Yo no suelo votar a negativo a las personas que tienen 1 de reputación, no le veo sentido a perder 1 de reputación por alguien que no pierde nada :)

Comment: @Luiggi En estas preguntas que sabemos que se van a borrar, no se pierde reputación, se recupera apenas se borra la respuesta. El tema es permitir que un 4k pueda eliminarla (además de marcarle al resto de la comunidad que no vale la pena).

Comment: @Mariano ni así le voto en negativo, pero creo que es más sobre opinión personal.